# Save remote picture to server error

Tags: php

I am trying to get a remote picture and save it to my server likeso:

```
file_put_contents('/public/assets/images/upload/vid_thumb/'.$filename, file_get_contents($data));
```

`$data` leads to a picture url "http://something.jpg" and `$filename` is just that URL string shortened to "something.jpg".

I don't understand this, everytime I get this Error: "failed to open stream: No such file or directory". I enabled allow furl open in my server settings. And believe me above path leads from my root directory.

EDIT: I am using Codeigniter + Bonfire if that is causing problems

EDIT2:

Solved!

I had to put in the whole path to my local file not just from the web root directory. I used getcwd() and the path was: "C:\Program Files\wamp\www\public..." Why noone mentiones this when searcing for file_put_contents ?

Comment: you can use `copy` instead of `file_put_contents` and `file_get_contents` http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: Tried, get same error

Comment: then the problem must be in `$data` can you post the value of `$data`

Comment: It must be my path, full error reads "Message: file_put_contents(/public/assets/images/upload/vid_thumb/hqdefault.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your php INI setting for **allow_url_fopen** is set to ON

more info : http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: /public/assets/images/upload/vid_thumb/ must not exist then.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I had to put in the whole path to my local file not just from the web root directory. I used `getcwd()` and the path was: "C:\Program Files\wamp\www\public..." Why noone mentiones this when searcing for `file_put_contents` ?